# add an alert if div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#textDiv:empty').hide();
});
```

But I want to add a jquery function in case the div `#textDiv` is not empty. I want to add an alert if it is not empty. I tried this code without success.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#textDiv').text().length == 0 ){
        alert ("please add players below");
    }
});
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: empty div regarding html? or empty div regarding text?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `$('#textDiv').text().length`, I assume it's text

Comment: But in his first code that 'works' he used `:empty` which is for HTML

Comment: OP: `$('#textDiv:not(:empty)')` is CSS pseudo-selector for non-empty divs

Comment: the div is sometimes empty of text.

Comment: is the text wrapped in any p? span? may need to see some html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `text()` [text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get the html/text inside the div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#textDiv').text() == '') // Change the condition for emapty and not empty
  {
    alert ("please add players below");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv"></div>
```

Comment: you should add an explanation so OP understands the issue and knows how to avoid in future. Avoids a copy/paste generation of coders

Comment: Yes @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs added
will add more in details

Comment: Consider using `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: @Yuri Ohhh Yes, Updated

Answer (score 1):

The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements. It is different from the .html() functions. Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.

You are better off with creating a function which checks if the div has any html or not and return true or false respectively.

```
 (function($){
        jQuery.fn.checkEmpty = function() {
           return !$.trim(this.html()).length;
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

Use :

```
<div id="selector"></div>
```

On document ready, call this function with your div and it would alert according to the condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#selector").checkEmpty()){
         alert("Empty");
    }else{
         alert("Not Empty");
    }
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
if ( $('#textDiv').html() == 0 ) 
{alert ("please add players below");}
});

Comment: you should add an explanation so OP understands the issue and knows how to avoid in future. Avoids a copy/paste generation of coders

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CSS Pseudo-Classes`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to access items in `jQuery`:

---

```js
if ($('.textDiv:empty')) {
  alert('First Empty');
}

if ($('.textDiv:not(:empty)')) {
  alert ("Second not Empty\nplease add players below");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textDiv">Empty : No child elements</div>
<br>
<div class="textDiv">
  <p>Not Empty : Has child elements</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `length` before `hide` else alert.

```js
if ($('#textDiv:empty').length !== 0)
  $('#textDiv:empty').hide();
else
 alert ("please add players below");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv">Test Contain For Alert</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (!$('#textDiv').text().length){
    alert ("please add players below");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textDiv"></div>
```